# Let's Encrypt: ClientID reqistered under application settings differs from what I entered?

Tags: azure, ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

So I am trying to get Let's Encrypt working on Windows Azure through the web extension but I am getting a error that I cannot solve or find any information about.

I am following this tutorial on how to set ut Let's Encrypt on Azure:

https://github.com/sjkp/letsencrypt-siteextension/wiki/How-to-install#create-a-service-principal

When I use the extension wizard, fill in all the fields and press next this is the error I get:

[image]

My resourcegroup:

[image]

My serviceplan inside my resourcegroup (+ storage and app service):

[image]

My ClientID (application id):

[image]

My secret is also set, saved the value and pasted it into the wizard:

[image]

My connection strings are set (in the format mentioned in the tutorial/setup):

[image]

There is a webjob running, I did not create this, I think it was created by the wizard in some way(?):

[image]

And at last:

[image]

It seems to me that I have done everything the tutorial has asked me to do, I don't know why I get the error, I also don't understand the reference to "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". Does anyone know what I did wrong and how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the Update Application Settings checkbox?

Comment: That did the trick, I thought I already had set those settings before and therefore I did not check that box.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The checkbox "Update Application Settings" must be checked if you want to modify the settings from the Let's Encrypt extension's pages.

Comment: Thanks. It saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you hate the idea of an azure webjob swallowing valuable system resources of your azure app service then there is now an alternative solution which uses Azure Automation;

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/GetSSL-LetsEncrypt

Documentation @ https://w.itpro.es/ssl-eng